# How to manage int when it's incremented inside another loop?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, int

I have a simple loop with an int counter that gets incremented inside a while loop when a special case exists.  My question is simply - how should I manage memory inside this function with regards to the int specifically?  I've been using NSNumber almost exclusively and what little time I've spent with int seems to make me think I'm not doing releasing it correctly.

Any other improvements are also welcome but I'm very interested in the int question

```
- (NSArray *)parseJson:(NSArray *) items
{
  NSMutableArray* hats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSEnumerator *enumerator = [items objectEnumerator];
  NSDictionary* item;
  int counterz = 0;
  while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
    Hat* hat = [[Hat alloc] init];

    hat.addr = [item objectForKey:@"Address"];

    BOOL* hasHat = [item objectForKey:@"HasHat"];

    if ([hasHat boolValue]) {
      if (counterz < 10) {
        [hats addObject:hat];
        counterz++;
      }
    }
  }

  return hats;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple unnecessary things and some memory leaks...

```
- (NSArray *)parseJson:(NSArray *) items {
  NSMutableArray *hats = [NSMutableArray array];
  int counter = 0;
  for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    Hat *hat = [[Hat alloc] init];
    [hat setAddr:[item objectForKey:@"Address"]];
    BOOL hasHat = [[item objectForKey:@"HasHat"] boolValue];
    if (hasHat && counter < 10) {
      [hats addObject:hat];
      counter++;
    }
    [hat release];
  }
  return hats;
}
```

And heck, once you reach a `counter` of 10, you could `break` out of the loop, because you're never going to do anything useful once 10 is reached.

Some other comments:

- The name of the method is wrong.  Nothing about this method has to do with *parsing* JSON.  At best you're interpreting an array of dictionaries that happened to *originate* from a JSON string, but there's nothing about the nature of this code that says "this is parsing JSON".
- `-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]` returns an object.  A `BOOL` is not an object, it's a primitive (like an `int` or `char`).  Appending `*` to the type does not make it an object either. :)
- Since the method name does not begin with `new` or `alloc` and does not contain the word `copy`, you're supposed to return an autoreleased object from it.  The method in the question was returning an owned object (+1 retain count), since you invoked `alloc`, but never `autorelease`.  Using the convenience constructor `+array` fixes this.
- In your loop, you allocated a `Hat` object, but never released it.  This is a classic memory leak.

Comment: +1 For all the fixes, although you didn't actually address the "how to memory manage an int" aspect of question. (Then again, I ignored all the rest.) :-)

Comment: @Dave DeLong Yours is still a vastly more useful response IMHO, that said.

Comment: Whoa - best answer ever! Thank you much!!!  About the strange behavior of calling one object but it's type being another (that was a mistake when I was cleaning the method for SO) - edited both Q&A (sorry for this mistake on my part)

Comment: Now if the static analyser could do this, Apple would *really* be on to something. :-)

Comment: @middaparka no doubt - I'm just glad to have experienced engineers watching over a weekend iPhone hack like myself :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to release a "normal" (i.e.: non-object based) `int` - it'll happily life out its (brief, tragic) life on the stack until it falls out of scope.

Comment: @Bavarious Actually had stack in there initially and then changed to heap. Will update to include both, I think. :-)

Comment: Sorry; that `sed` command means stack instead of heap. :-P Automatic variables live on the stack.

Comment: @Bavarious  Ah - you were referring to the first iteration of my answer. (Damn, it's getting confusing now.) :-)